# Delete sub word Android Studio / IntelliJ

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I ctrl modifier with arrow keys to jump caret and delete by words.

I am wondering if there is a way to have this behaviour modified by android studio, so it jumps/deletes by sub words. I am used to using SublimeText as my editor, where I have enabled this behaviour.

So...

ThisWouldBeFiveDeletes

and

this_would_be_five_deletes

Thanks for any direction you can provide. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Preferences menu, under the `Editor -> General -> Smart Keys` sub-menu, check off `Use "CamelHumps" words`.

[image]

Comment: It works like a charm, thanks. Now with Command+Option+Right i move subword (not whole word).